# How do I manage controllers or mvc-implementations?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, single-page-application

I am trying to understand the mvc-pattern. I am developing an Singe Page Application in pure Java Script + jQuery.

Let's say we have an 'Configuration' for the app, where you can change different aspect. You can see multiple tabs (User, Security, etc.).

At the moment I have:

- UserModel
- UserView
- UserController
- SecurityModel
- SecurityView
- SecurityController
- AdministrationViewModel (where I combine UserModel&ColorModel)
- AdministrationController
- AdministrationView (provides the 'tabs' and should show the views on them)

What I don't understand is, how to change between the controllers? Where do I change them?

Let consider this flow:

1. User sees empty, basic structure of the application
2. User clicks on 'Security-Configuration' at the navigation-bar
3. User should see now 'Security-Configuration' (and the tabs |Security||User|)
4. User clicks on the tab 'User'
5. User should see now View for 'User-Configuration'

   - When do I initialise the controllers?
   - Who is responsible for choosing the right controller?
   - And how do I user the controllers for the partials view in AdministrationController?

EDIT: As I didn't mentioned it: There is a REST-Service in the background. So my calls to the backend are just ajax-post/get-calls.

Comment: Despite the question is actually interesting, I think there are **too many problems** addressed in the **same question**; Additionally, none of the exposed problem is actually a practical, reproducible one but, rather, abstract. I'm not exactly sure whether this can be considered in topic here, though, once again, the question is definitely interesting from a theorical point of view.

Comment: I think u should read Angular.Js docs. It might give u some understanding about MVC implementation.

Comment: @briosheje. I think you are right =) It was a little bit difficult for me to seperate the actual problem. Maybe I can isolate it as far as I am working on it

Comment: @ridoansaleh: I found tons of examples of MVC when there is one Model, one View and one Controller. Maybe the solution is simple and I am overlooking it.

Answer (score -1):

IMHO, with SPA/PWA, you need to think of MVC as mvC. IOW just use ES6,CSS3,HTML5 to call your controller methods as required. No Views and no Models are necessary.

Please also note that as *no* URL routing is required then not router logic/code is required either. (Apart from your Global.asax or whatever it is with .Net Core)

It is a very simple, powerful, and effective methodology! JSON In <-> JSON Out.

Forgot to mention, most people opt for the /ControllerName/MethodName convention for URLs as for example: -

Global.asax: -

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
             );

 }
```

Example DataController method: -

```
    public JsonResult GetDetails(int custId)
    {
        Customer result = customers.Find(x => x.Id == custId);
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Example Javascript invocation: -

```
const CUST_DATA_URL = "http://localhost:49263/data/GetDetails";

function idSelect(elem, rowKey, rowData) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var custArgs = "custId=" + rowKey;

    callAJAX(CUST_DATA_URL, "POST", function (xmlhttp) {
        if (xmlhttp.responseText.length == 0){
            alert("No such Customer");
            return;
        }
        crud.style.display = "block";
        logScroll.style.display = "none";
        resetSearch();

        var resp = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        detailId.value    = resp.Id;
        detailName.value  = resp.Name;
        detailEmail.value = resp.Email;

    }, custArgs);
}

function callAJAX(url, method, callback, serverArgs)
{
    var callback = callback;
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var target = url;
    var args = (serverArgs != undefined) ? serverArgs : "";
    var postArgs = "";
    var callbackArgs = new Array();

    for (var i = 4; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        callbackArgs[i - 3] = arguments[i];
    }

    callbackArgs[0] = xmlhttp;

    if (method.toUpperCase() == "GET") {
        target = target + "?" + args;
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                callback.apply(this, callbackArgs)
            } else {
                throw new Error("Error making Ajax call to " + target + " Status = " + xmlhttp.status);
            }
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open(method, url, true);
    if (method.toUpperCase() == "POST") {
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        postArgs = args;
    }
    xmlhttp.send(postArgs);
}
```

Comment: So a down-vote with no comment. typical from React/Angular bloatware fan bois. @dipa2016 can you explain what the solution doesn't do for you?

Comment: Yeah I know it wasn't you mate. Just wondering if there is anything more I can do to help/explain?

Comment: Sorry for late response. Priorities changed a little bit. I cannot get your example. I don't have any global.asax. My project it's clear Web (JS, HTML5 and CSS). You can see the REST as pure data access. No, or very few business rules are handled there.

Comment: If you don't have a global.asax the I guess you're using .NET CORE. So the routing would be RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes); I guess. What can't yo get from the example?